# Python2.6 IF Using AND OR

Tags: python

I can't compare one variable with multiple values.

For example I need that variable called `_query` must be different from `Sleep` and `Binlog`.

```
if (query != "Sleep") or (query != "Binlog Dump"):
    print query[4]
```

With the above code my script is not working. Could you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Your title says "AND OR". Have you tried your expression with `and` instead of `or`?

Comment: because i think that maybe i need use "and" in order to solve the problem... probably i wrong...

Comment: No, you're right, you need `and` - so why do you think you need `or`?

Comment: Quote: *"I need that variable called _query must be different from Sleep **and** Binlog"* (emphasis is mine). Yes... you should use the `and` operator! :) However, this solution doesn't scale well if you have to test your value against a long list of others. See my answer if that is your scenario.

Comment: Is the variable `query` or `_query`, and is the second pattern `"Binlog"` or `"Binlog Dump"`?

Comment: This is not a programming question, it's a logical one, and as such it's best answered by thinking a little bit rather than trying to ask others about it.

Answer (score 2):

Think about it. `query` will *always* be not equal to either `"Sleep"` or `"Binlog Dump"` -- it can't ever be equal to both of them -- and an `or` expression is true if *either* of its arguments is true. So your condition will always be true! What you want is:

```
if not (query == "Sleep" or query == "Binlog Dump"):
```

With some Boolean algebra applied, this is logically equivalent to the following:

```
if query != "Sleep" and query != "Binlog Dump":
```

But the first is easier to read because it expresses your intent more clearly: if the query is not either of those two terms.

This condition can also be written clearly as:

```
if query not in ("Sleep", "Binlog Dump"):
```

This has the advantage of being easily expanded to additional terms if needed, and it is also arguably even more readable than the first example. Also, you don't need to repeat the variable name you're testing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the obvious?

```
if _query not in ('Sleep', 'Binlog'):
    print _query
```

It's also probably the most Pythonic idiom.